# NotifierProvider re-build every update and the value is not updated

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am relatively new to `Riverpod`, so I got a weird issue with `NotifierProvider`. This is my notifier:

```
@riverpod
class CoachPosition extends _$CoachPosition {
  @override
  int build() {
    logger.e("Build CoachPosition");
    return 0;
  }

  void updatePosition(int position) {
    state = position;
  }
}
```

This is my widget to fetch and show a list of coaches (it's working fine). I got about 5 coaches.

```
 final coachesWidget = ref.watch(fetchCoachPreviewsProvider).when(
      data: (List<CoachPreview> list) {
        return CarouselSlider.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) => _FlipCard(list[itemIndex]),
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: double.infinity,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            enlargeFactor: 0.2,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              logger.e("onPageChanged: $index");
              ref.read(coachPositionProvider.notifier).updatePosition(index);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      error: (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        return const Center(
          child: Icon(Icons.error),
        );
      },
      loading: () {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
```

This is my button to check the coach position:

```
          SizedBox(
            height: 48,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final index = ref.read(coachPositionProvider);
                logger.e("start session with coach index: $index");
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                ),
                elevation: 4.0,
              ),
              child: const Text("Start Session", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.black54)),
            ),
          ),
```

The issue is whenever I changed the `CarouselSlider`, the index changed and the `updatePosition` method was called. However, the log `logger.e("Build CoachPosition");` was shown all the time. Is it normal? As far as I understand, it should be called only once. Then when I pressed on the `"Start Session"` Button, the value is `0`. What's the solution for the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `coachPositionProvider` is not currently listened on by other providers|widgets, then it will be recreated each time. To change this behavior, either start listening to it permanently (for example, try using `ref.listen`), or add the `keepAlive` parameter to the annotation:

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class CoachPosition extends _$CoachPosition {...}
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying it. `ref.listen` works fine to me.